# User Profile Service reconfiguration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

What is best practice to recreate User Profile service application in SharePoint 2013 Production.

Could we export the custom user properties before deleting UPA.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need to write a custom code to get those properties from Profile after recreation import those.

I find this [User Profile Properties](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/11/user-profile-properties/), with this code you will able to export the existing properties from UPA.

```
public override int Run(string command, StringDictionary keyValues, out string output)
   2: {
   3:  output = string.Empty;
   4:  
   5:  InitParameters(keyValues);
   6:  
   7:  ServerContext serverContext = ServerContext.GetContext(Params["sspname"].Value);
   8:  UserProfileConfigManager manager = new UserProfileConfigManager(serverContext);
   9:  PropertyCollection properties = manager.GetProperties();
  10:  
  11:  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  12:  
  13:  XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
```

Also check this one
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20692.sharepoint-2013-get-set-and-copy-user-profile-properties-using-powershell.aspx

But if you dont have too many custom properties, then simply go the Central admin page > manage service on server > User profile Service application > on this page click on user properties....you can write it down and then manually create it.